# Hamcrest matcher to compare two collections of different types by items using a custom matcher for items

Tags: java, matcher, hamcrest

I have two collections of objects. The objects in these two collections are of different types, and there is a custom matcher to check that they refer to the same thing. Also, the collections are in the same order. Say, we can compare the entities in these collections by name, they are sorted by that name, and we have a custom matcher that returns true if the names are the same.

What I need is a matcher that would iterate over both of these collections item by item and compare those pairs using the existing custom matcher (i can also modify it).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's what i mean:

`List lA =....;
List lB =....;`

// what i have:

for (int i = 0; i < lA.size(); i++) {
    assertThat(lA.get(i), matchesUsingMyCustomMatcher(lB.get(i));
}

// what i would like to have
assertThat(lA, someMagicMatcher(myModifiedCustomMatcher(lB)));

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider this test:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    List<MyType1> expected = ...;
    List<MyType2> actual = ...;

    assertThat(actual, containsUsingCustomMatcher(expected));
}
```

You can use the following helper function (`matchesUsingMyCustomMatcher` is the same function as in your example).

```
private Matcher<Iterable<? extends MyType2>> containsUsingCustomMatcher(List<MyType1> items) {
    List<Matcher<? super MyType2>> matchers = new ArrayList<Matcher<? super MyType2>>();
    for (MyType1 item : items) {
        matchers.add(matchesUsingMyCustomMatcher(item));
    }
    return Matchers.contains(matchers);
}
```

---

### Generic approach

For a more reusable approach maybe the following can help you. First we need a generic helper function.

```
public static <T, R> Matcher<Iterable<? extends R>> containsUsingCustomMatcher(List<T> items, MatcherFunction<T, R> matcherFunction) {
    return Matchers.contains(createMatchers(items, matcherFunction));
}

private static <R, T> List<Matcher<? super R>> createMatchers(List<T> items, MatcherFunction<T, R> matcherFunction) {
    List<Matcher<? super R>> matchers = new ArrayList<Matcher<? super R>>();
    for (T item : items) {
        matchers.add(matcherFunction.apply(item));
    }
    return matchers;
}
```

and an interface `MatcherFunction`. The implementation of this interface has to create the appropriate matchers

```
public interface MatcherFunction<T, R> {
    Matcher<R> apply(T t);
}
```

Example usage to achieve the same as in the first part of this answer:

```
assertThat(actual, containsUsingCustomMatcher(expected, myCustomMatcherFunction()));
```

with

```
private MatcherFunction<MyType1, MyType2> myCustomMatcherFunction() {
    return new MatcherFunction<MyType1, MyType2>() {

        @Override
        public Matcher<MyType2> apply(MyType1 t) {
            return matchesUsingMyCustomMatcher(t);
        }
    };
}
```

**Java 8 note:**

These anonymous classes look kind of ugly. With Java 8 you can simply write

```
assertThat(actual, containsUsingCustomMatcher(expected, this::matchesUsingMyCustomMatcher));
```